# cakephp contain twice model association

Tags: cakephp, associations, containable

I have to fetch data from `posts` table

which has `foreign keys` (
 `category_id` references to `categories.id`
 `created_by` references to `users.id`,
 `updated_by` references to `users.id`
 )

I can fetch `created_by` `username` but not both

```
$this->Post->Behaviors->load('Containable');

        $this->paginate = array(
            'conditions' => array('Post.category_id' => $id),
            'order' => array('title'),
            'contain' => array(
                'User'=>array(
                        'fields'=>array('id','first_name','last_name','username'),
                        'conditions' => array('User.id = Post.created_by')
                    ),
                //posts table has 2 fields(created_by & updated_by) associated with users table
                //'User'=>array(
                //        'fields'=>array('id','first_name','last_name','username'),
                //        'conditions' => array('User.id = Post.updated_by')
                //    ),
                'Category'=>array(
                    'Type'=>array(
                        'fields'=>array('id','type_name')
                        )
                    ),
            )
        );
```

//post model

```
 public $belongsTo = array(
    'User'=> array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'created_by',
        'foreignKey' => 'updated_by'
    ),

);
```

//user model

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Post' => array(
        'className' => 'Post',
        'foreignKey' => array('created_by','updated_by'),
    ),
);
```

how to show both and alias both Users as (`created_by` & `updated_by`)

Comment: In your Post model, did you define the TWO _belongsTo_ relationships between Post and User? That alias (relationship name) is what you use for Containable behavior.

Comment: 2 models added in edit (Post and User)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to define two relationships in the Post model

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'CreatedUser'=> array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'created_by'
    ),
    'UpdatedUser'=> array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'updated_by'
    )
);
```

Now create the converse relationships in the User model.

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'CreatedPosts' => array(
        'className' => 'Post',
        'foreignKey' =>'created_by'
    ),
    'UpdatedPosts' => array(
        'className' => 'Post',
        'foreignKey' => 'updated_by'
    ),
);
```

Then the find()

```
$this->Post->Behaviors->load('Containable');

$this->paginate = array(
        'conditions' => array('Post.category_id' => $id),
        'order' => array('title'),
        'contain' => array(
            'CreatedUser'=>array(
                    'fields'=>array('id','first_name','last_name','username')
                ),
            'UpdatedUser'=>array(
                    'fields'=>array('id','first_name','last_name','username')
                ),
            'Category'=>array(
                'Type'=>array(
                    'fields'=>array('id','type_name')
                    )
                ),
        )
    );
```